# Delete integer array value from numbers

Tags: php, sql

I have 50 values stored in this form in a field in my table, comma-separated (for example: `472744,341750,263249,...`

I can query that field in that table. I want to convert the values to array and delete a specific value from the array.  Below is my code but it refuses to work. Can anyone explain why?

```
public function getChurchPinInfo($id)
{
    $query = $this->db -> prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM  church_pin_tbl WHERE church_id = ? LIMIT 1"
    );
    $query -> execute(array($id));
    $result = $query->fetch();

    return $result;
}
```

and then

```
$churchPinsArray = array((new Shop)->getChurchPinInfo($churchId)->pin);

if (($key = array_search(341750, $churchPinsArray)) !== false) {
    unset($churchPinsArray[$key]);
    print_r($churchPinsArray);
} else {
    echo 'Not found';
}
```

Comment: _" it refuses to work"_ means what exactly?

Comment: What are you doing ? What are this numbers ? What is the format you want for your final array ? What value did you want to delete ?

Comment: $churchPinsArray is a multidimentional array now, so it's values will be arrays, never the value '341750'

Comment: I want to remove one of those numbers from $churchPinsArray and send the rest back to my table field.  The numbers in  the field are stored in this form 472744,341750,263249,1599,144858,253798 and they are 50 in numbers seperated by comma. i want to delete any of the value in the list of number as far as that  velue is in that sequence of values.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is that you check for the assignment "*$key = array_search(341750, $churchPinsArray)*" to not be false when you rather want to check if $key is false **after** the assignment. Also since $churchPinsArray is already an array, the second row should not be needed. This should work:

```
$churchPinsArray = array((new Shop)->getChurchPinInfo($churchId)->pin);
$key = array_search(341750, $churchPinsArray);
if ($key !== false) {
    unset($churchPinsArray[$key]);
    print_r($churchPinsArray);
} else {
    echo 'Not found';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1st is, as @0x7a31c7 already stated, the condition in your if clause (see his answer for details).

2nd is the structure of your input array. You do *twice* a `$a=array($b)`, which will result in a structure like that:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(472744) [1]=> int(341750) } } }
```

so your actual values are hidden in 3rd level.

```
<?php
// faking your class Shop, just to get the values and keep the usage.
class Shop {
    public function getChurchPinInfo($param) {
        $obj = new stdClass();
        $obj->pin = [472744,341750,263249,1599,144858,253798,754799,383614,788891,677710,89459,311053,829971,131015,148773,917765,183785,585969,869224,290385,598292,88728,449330,569776,225002,659463,249129,831123,341116,755784,199342,911099,570201,909965,18753,117324,521260,802112,241925,190324];
        return $obj;
    }
}

// don't need the array() around that:
$churchPinsArray = (new Shop)->getChurchPinInfo(42)->pin;
// $churchPinsArray = array($churchPinsArray); // this doesn't make sense anyway.
$key = array_search(341750, $churchPinsArray);
if($key !== false) {
    echo "removing item at position $key: {$churchPinsArray[$key]}<br>\n";
    unset($churchPinsArray[$key]);
    var_dump($churchPinsArray);
} else {
    echo 'Not found';
}
```

Comment: thanks for contributing, i have added my public function structure. as your structure does not match mine. please help.

Comment: I still don't know what the actual return of this function is. Looks like `pin` could be a string!? Can you add the result of a `var_dump((new Shop)->getChurchPinInfo($churchId))`; ?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the answer to my question
i succeded in converting that values sepearated by comma to an array and then remove a value from the list of array before imploding the array

```
$churchPinList = (new Shop)->getChurchPinInfo($churchId)->pin;

$arr = explode(',', $churchPinList);
$churchPinsArray = array_map('intval', $arr);

$arrayWithoutUsedPin = array_diff($churchPinsArray, array($churchPin));
$newPins = implode(',', $arrayWithoutUsedPin);
echo $newPins;
```